# Dúvida Http x Https Android

Tags: java, android, https

Estou criando uma aplicação Android. Essa que chama arquivos PHP via HttpPost.

Pergunto: o que muda eu chamar com https em vez de http (Parto do ponto que utilizarei https, já com certificado no servidor instalado).

A dúvida seria na prática, o que muda nesses dados? Eles são criptografados? Inclusive os parámetros?

Como posso ver o output dessa criptografia.

Comment: Sua dúvida é referente a Http vs Https, não tem nada a ver com android.

Answer (score 1):

A comunicação Https é criptografada. Na prática qualquer intermediário que intercepte seus pacotes e não possua a chave privada não irá conseguir ler sua mensagem.

Para ver o output basta instalar um sniffer na sua máquina, tipo wireshark, e ficar escutando conexões https e http. Logo verá que a mensagem https estará criptografada.